# Loading and Desplaying Image in External Class in Processing

Tags: java, image, class, 2d, processing

First a little back-story so I don't get trapped in an "I want X but really need Y problem". Me and two of my friends are making a 2d game in java using Processing for all of the image manipulation. To that end we're writing a more fully functional image class that can handle animations as well as static images. I would like to load an image from within that class but as it is not a subclass of PApplet the loadImage(filename) function is not available. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I eventually came up with was to create a static variable in my main class that extended papplet to keep track of the instance of the main class. This variable could then be referenced by any other class.